# Reusing "settings" across different method calls

Tags: web-services, oop

This question uses Java examples, but it deals with a problem that is applicable to any OOP. I want to expose some webservices so other applications can use them. I created a jar/library file which handles all the connection stuff and the conversion between string/xml to pojo. I created a "facade" class which has 1 method for each invokable webservice. E.g. in pseudocode:

```
class ServiceInvoker 
{
   //constructor
   ...

   //methods
   public List<Product> getProducts()
   public ProductReference getProductReferences(int productId)
   ...
}
```

Problem is, most of the webservices require a bunch of parameters. For example, whenever you're dealing with products you either get full detailed information, or you can get only the most basic information. Same for only recent/old information. It is more performant to get only a few products but sometimes you really need more information so to parameters exist to cater all use cases in the best way. I found 3 possible ways of dealing with this.

1. Add the necessary parameters to each method call. Advantage: simple to understand, it is clear when invoking the method what you're "settings" are.
2. Create a few setters in the ServiceInvoker like this:

> public void setInfoMode(Infomode mode)
>       {
>            this.infoMode = mode;
>       }

Where InfoMode would be an enum class like this: InfoMode.DETAILED, InfoMode.BASIC. The advantage of this scheme is that developers only have to set the mode "once" and then all future service invocations would use that mode. This can save a whole bunch of arguments in several methods, especially because some services can share settings and it is likely the same service is invoked multiple times. The main disadvantage of this scheme is clarity: when calling the service "getProducts", the response can vary wildly depending on earlier set modes. The earlier said advantage would be lost if developers had to do some preprocessing like this:

```
if (serviceInvoker.getInfoMode != InfoMode.DETAILED)
{
    serviceInvoker.setInfoMode(InfoMode.DETAILED);
}
```

Because this is more complex than simply passing the modes along as an argument.

The third option would be to combine both 1 and 2. Have a method without parameters, that uses the modes set earlier, but also provide a method with does takes arguments and these would temporarily overwrite the set modes for that method invocation. The disadvantage of this scheme is the "doubling" of all methods. Suddenly my invoker class becomes huge and it starts to smell like the anti-pattern "huge god class".

What are some best practices around this issue? Do design pattern exists for this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is probably going to wind up closed as being primarily opinion-based (because it is), but it's cleaner to just represent specific request types as DTOs. When you call a class a "ServiceInvoker", I'm thinking Command Pattern. What this means for your design is that the arguments to your Facade should be self-explanatory packages that encapsulate all the info required for the service to perform its duties. This design should also eliminate the need for multiple methods in your class.

What this means for callers of your service is that they'll pass different argument types (that have a common ancestor) to a single entry point in your `ServiceInvoker`, `ServiceInvoker#invoke`. This  method will then take classes that all extend `ProductRequest`. `ServiceInvoker` can then delegate the request to the appropriate command handler. To Illustrate

1. Create a base class `ProductRequest`. This base class should contain the info that'll be common to all operation types

   ```
    public abstract class ProductRequest{
      private InfoMode infoMode;
      private String requestType;
      //getters and setters

      //trying to avoid violating Javabean convention here
      private void setRequestName(){
         this.requestType = this.getClassName().toString();
      }
    }
   ```
2. Individual service request types should extend `ProductRequest`. Customize as necessary for each operation type.
3. Create specialized `ProductRequestHandler` types that will handle specific operation requests. Let's try one that specifically handles product reference requests

   ```
     public class ProductReferenceReqHandler implements ProductRequestHandler<ProductReferenceRequest>{

         @Override
         public ProductResponse handleRequest(ProductReferenceRequest req){
          //implementation grime goes here
         }

     }
   ```
4. You should have stack of `ProductRequestHandler`s in a map, keyed by the request type. This map should be a member of your `ServiceInvoker`
5. With access to a map of possible request handlers, your invoker only need have one method: `invoke`

   ```
      public class ServiceInvoker{
           private Map<String,ProductRequestHandler> handlers;
           //work out some logic to instantiate and populate the map with the available handlers

           public ProductResponse invoke(ProductRequest req){
             ProductRequestHandler handler = handlers.get(req.getRequestType());
             ProductResponse resp =  handler.handleRequest(req);

           }

      }
   ```

---

What you get is a clean, flexible interface that avoids unnecessary clutter in your Facade and gives an intuitive contract (by means of intuitively named DTOs) to your clients

Comment: Excellent design pattern! One suggestion though: instead of relying on a map of "handlers", I forced every request class to have a method getHandler() (I did this by making an abstract method in the baseRequest class which every other request inherits), which returns the appropiate handler. This handler is actually a static final attribute of the request class, so it will not lead to spurious instantiation of handler objects.

Comment: @user1884155 - That's a bit of an anti-pattern. The request classes are supposed to be request-data only. The request classes should have no knowledge of their execution context or the handler to be invoked. By baking in the handler information into the request, you also lose the flexibility a map of handlers would've given you. Having a map of handlers means you can add or remove handlers at will, or even redesignate some handlers to handle different request types

Comment: I don't immediately see why the request is not allowed to have a method "suggestedHandler". The serviceInvoker is in no way obliged to actually use that handler, it can use any handler it wants (if the context justifies it) and the request has no knowledge of what it means "to be invoked". The only thing the request class says is "Hey, if anybody wants a handler that can handle me, why not try this default one?". This is basic polymorphism which is definitely not an anti-pattern. Populating a hashmap hardcoded with request->handler data does smell like an anti-pattern (maintainability?)

Comment: @user1884155 - if you're putting it that way (as in it's just for information purposes only), then it may be acceptable. A hashmap with a command-commandHandler mapping is definitely not an anti-pattern; it's the stuff of the Service Locator pattern. You do have a point in that it may be unwieldy by way of the hardcoding, it looks better when the handlers are configured externally or better yet, using a DI framework like spring. From a "purity" standpoint, the DTO is supposed to be completely oblivious of its execution environment.

Comment: I see the point you're making. I'll try to implement it and examine if the advantages of the service locator pattern outweigh the disadvantages (as described clearly in the wikipedia article). Thanks!